# Excel VBA Chart With Multiple Series But Same X Value

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to put together a VB script in Excel which creates a 'Stacked Bar Chart'.

From examples found in this [site](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/VBAExcelXYCharts.html), I did the following code:

```
Sub AddNewSeries()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlBarStacked).Select
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$E$3")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPStart")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPBC")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$H$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPBT")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$I$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPEC")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$J$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPFin")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$K$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPIMS")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$L$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPInf")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$M$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPT")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$N$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPSols")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
    End With
End Sub
```

You'll see that rather than using cell references, I use named ranges because the data will be dynamic.

The code does run without any errors displayed, but the last series used i.e.

```
.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$N$4")
```

overwrites the previously plotted data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the series one at at time. You are adding one series, and keep changing (overwriting) the properties of that series. Thus you end up with just one series, with the properties that you specified.

The following might work better:

```
Sub AddNewSeries()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlBarStacked).Select
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$E$3")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPStart")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPBC")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$H$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPBT")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$I$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPEC")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
         .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$J$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPFin")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$K$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPIMS")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$L$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPInf")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$M$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPT")
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPPN")
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$N$4")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("IFPSols")
    End With
End Sub
```

It is possible that you need a

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
```

Right after the `AddChart2` statement - on my machine, it tried to "guess" a series and got it very very wrong… but the above removed it and left me just the "good" series.

Also - I found that on the Mac, I could not use `AddChart2` but had to use `AddChart` instead. Not sure if that matters for you.

Comment: Hi @Floris, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Your solution worked great and also highlighted an error in my original recorded macro. All the best and kind regards

Comment: `AddChart2` replaced `AddChart` in Excel 2013 for Windows and Excel 2016 for Mac, though for backwards compatibility you can still use `AddChart`. `AddChart2` makes it easier to use the newer, nicer chart styles introduced in Excel 2013.